# Get correct directory path when moving uploaded files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, directory

I need to get the correct directory path for my codeigniter application.

I need to send all of my uploaded files in this directory:

```
localhost/myapplication/uploads/temp1
```

I have tried putting this code in my directory path for my mkdir, copy and unlink files:

```
$tempDirectory = base_url().'uploads/temp'.$somestring.'/';
```

But I realized that http addresses are not applicable when moving files. How do I move my files to the directory I want in my application?

Answer (score 1):

As [CodeIgniter wiki](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) says in an example..

`$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/temp1/';`

Comment: What about if I don't want to use the codigniter function?

Comment: Then use `get_include_path()` and `set_include_path()` :)